# Could a System.Diagnostics.Process instance be garbage collected?

Tags: c#, mono

I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process class to convert wav file to mp3 file in a separated process.  The method that does the job like this:

```
    public void ConvertWavToMp3 (TempFile srcFile, string title, Action<TempFile, Exception> complete)
    {
        var argument_fmt = "-S --resample 16 --tt {0} --add-id3v2  {1} {2}";
        var dstFile = new TempFile(Path.GetTempFileName());

        var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();

        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lame";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format (argument_fmt, 
                                                  title,
                                                  srcFile.Path,
                                                  dstFile.Path);

        proc.Exited += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            srcFile.Delete();
            complete(dstFile, null);
        };

        proc.Start();
    }
```

I'm worried about GC because as proc is only a local variable, theoretically it doesn't exist anymore when the method returns. Therefor, proc can be garbage collected and the callback function complete will never be called.

But I don't really want to record proc somewhere and dispose it after the process exits, as that would expose the internal mechanism of how the wav to mp3 conversion is implemented.

Is my concern about GC valid?  If GC of is potential problem, is there any way that I could prevent it without having to return the proc in this method?

BTW, I'm using Mono on linux.

**Edit**

Thanks for replies.  I'm confirmed that I need to keep a copy of the process.  So here's what I did:

```
public class LameConverter : IAudioConverter
{
    // We need to store a reference to the process in case it was GCed.
    IList<Process> _ProcList = new List<Process>();

    public void ConvertWavToMp3 (TempFile srcFile, string title, Action<TempFile, Exception> complete)
    {
                    // .. skipped ..
        proc.Exited += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            lock (this) {
                _ProcList.Remove(proc);             
            }
            proc.Dispose();
            srcFile.Delete();
            complete(dstFile, null);
        };

        proc.Start();

        lock (this) {
            _ProcList.Add(proc);
        }
    }
}
```

As long as the caller holds a reference to LameConverter, I don't need to worry about the GC anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object without a root in the application is a candidate for garbage collection.  In order to ensure that your callback fires you will need to find some place to store a reference to `proc` otherwise you will have undefined behavior.

One option in your case would be to return an object that encapsulates `proc` without exposing it via the public interface. Unfortunately in your case you must leak a bit of the underlying implementation to the caller of `ConvertWavToMp3` in order to ensure that the desired behavior occurs.

Comment: Very good observations, although one thing that does happen is since Proc uses internal resources that are being referenced by other internal code it may not get GCed but you are correct in saying he should keep that reference somewhere lest the process exit and the handler take too long (unless the proc reference is no longer needed)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate code sample that will work.  However, it will block the call to ConvertWavToMp3(...) while the process is executing.  Probably not what you want.

```
public void ConvertWavToMp3 (TempFile srcFile, string title, Action<TempFile, Exception> complete)
{
    var argument_fmt = "-S --resample 16 --tt {0} --add-id3v2  {1} {2}";
    var dstFile = new TempFile(Path.GetTempFileName());

    var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();

    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lame";
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format (argument_fmt, 
                                              title,
                                              srcFile.Path,
                                              dstFile.Path);

    using(var wh = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        proc.Exited += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            srcFile.Delete();
            complete(dstFile, null);
            wh.Set();
        };


        proc.Start();
        wh.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Like I said, this is probably not what you want, unless you're in, say, a console app.  If you're in a GUI app, keep a reference to your proc.  Something like:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    // other form stuff

    private System.Diagnostics.Process _encoderProc;

    private void doEncode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var argument_fmt = "-S --resample 16 --tt {0} --add-id3v2  {1} {2}";
        var dstFile = new TempFile(Path.GetTempFileName());

        var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process ();

        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "lame";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format (argument_fmt, 
                                                  title,
                                                  srcFile.Path,
                                                  dstFile.Path);

        proc.Exited += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            srcFile.Delete();

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                // INSERT CODE HERE: your UI-related stuff that you want to do with dstFile
                this._encoderProc = null;
            });
        };

        proc.Start();
        this._encoderProc = proc;
    }
}
```

Note the use of `BeginInvoke(...)`.  If you're going to do UI-related stuff, it needs to be on the UI thread, and that `Exited` event won't fire on the UI thread.  Hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.